# AssertEquals with Collections with non primitive template parameters

Tags: java, templates, collections, junit

I have a class for a string-number pair. This class has the method `compareTo` implemented.

A method of another class returns a collection of elements of the pair type.

I wanted to perform a unit test on this method, and therefore wrote the following:

```
@Test
public void testWeight() {

    Collection<StringNumber<BigDecimal>> expected = new Vector<StringNumber<BigDecimal>>();
    expected.add(new StringNumber<BigDecimal>("a", BigDecimal.ONE));
    expected.add(new StringNumber<BigDecimal>("b", BigDecimal.ONE));

    Collection<StringNumber<BigDecimal>> actual = new Vector<StringNumber<BigDecimal>>();
    expected.add(new StringNumber<BigDecimal>("a", BigDecimal.ONE));
    expected.add(new StringNumber<BigDecimal>("b", BigDecimal.ONE));

    //Collection<StringNumber<BigDecimal>> actual = A.f();

    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

But as you can see, the assertion fails, even though the elements in the collections are identical. What can be the reason?

The error I get is

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.Vector<[a:1, b:1]> 
>                              but was: java.util.Vector<[a:1, b:1]>

Which does not make scene to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StringNumber` class requires `equals()` method. Then it will work. Assuming this class contains `string` and `number` fields (auto-generated by my IDE):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof StringNumber)) {
        return false;
    }
    StringNumber that = (StringNumber) o;
    if (number != null ? !number.equals(that.number) : that.number != null) {
        return false;
    }
    return !(string != null ? !string.equals(that.string) : that.string != null);

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = string != null ? string.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (number != null ? number.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

Few remarks:

- Two `Vector`'s (why are you using such archaic data structure) are equal [if](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#equals(java.lang.Object)):

> both [...] have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal. (Two elements `e1` and `e2` are equal if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`.)

That's why overriding `equals()` is required.

- when implementing `equals()` you *must* implement `hashCode()`. Not required here, but better be safe than sorry: [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581).